# What can I use instead of <apex:tabPanel> in Lightning Experience

Tags: apex, tab, code, lightning-experience

I am using  in a Visualforce page to displaying of fields from an object that contains more than 100 fields and it is working as expected.

I want to create a version of this sort of layout in Lightning Experience. Please suggest how can I  display this on a Lightning Experience page from an object that contains more than 100 fields.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you check out the options available to you using Visualforce Lightning Design System. Here is link to a trailhead getting started tutorial [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en/project/workshop-lightning-design-system-visualforce)